# Finding most common range of numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that holds prices, the idea behind it is to have users suggest prices they think are reasonable for a good,example; range

Comment: Do you want `mean`, `median`, or `mode` of the suggested prices? It sounds like `median` but the repeating sounds like it could be `mode`.

Comment: Define 'most common'

Comment: More like the range with most rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the price by the range size, and then use `FLOOR()` to get the beginning of the range:

```
SELECT 1500*FLOOR(price/1500) AS price_base, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY price_base
ORDER BY count DESC
```

For example, `price_base = 3000` contains all prices from `3000` to `4499`, while `price_base = 4500` contains all prices from `4500` to `5999`.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong, in my case i do not know most numbers are between 4500 and 5000 the only thing i know is all prices are between 5 to 9000, so in your answer 1500 is what exactly?

Comment: How do you know the range size ?

Comment: `1500` is the size of the range. So this will show counts for `0-1499`, `1500-2999`, `3000-4499`, `4500-5999`, etc.

Comment: And `ORDER BY` will put the most common range first.

Comment: @Strawberry I took it from his example, `4500 to 6000` means he wants to group them in ranges of `1500`.

Comment: No. the range is given by statistical analysis of the data set.

Comment: @Strawberry Where does the question say that? If he wants to do cluster analysis, I think he'll have to use a statistical library in the client programming language, MySQL doesn't have that.

Comment: I could use MIN() to find smallest value and MAX() to find highest; this gives me the starting and ending point,  so to get the range size i could do something like COUNT(ABS(min -  max)) right?

Comment: @ThandiNgamu If you want to divide into 5 ranges, you could use `SELECT (max(price)-min(price))/5` as the range size.

Comment: The biggest problem i have is finding that range that which has most common values, in my case 4500 to 6000

Comment: Why doesn't my answer work for that?

Comment: It will show that the most common is `base_price = 4500`.

Comment: I think it works, thanks

Comment: your anwer is returning base_price as 0 and count 6

Comment: It seems like you removed too much in your description, it doesn't describe the problem in any useful way. Can you post the sample data that gives wrong results?